# Blogengine localhost working, server not

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, asp.net-web-api-routing, blogengine.net

Blogengine works perfectly on localhost, but when I transfer it to the server, setting App_Data to read/write, I cannot save settings, user info, actually anything but adding new pages.
I downloaded the blog using WebMatrix and uploaded it to the server without any changes.

When I test what is happening when I press "save" that is what I get from chrome:

Settings/Api | PUT | 404 Not found | text/html | angular.js:7889 Script

If I GET the same API everything is okay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i had same issue:
first of all make sure you website iis setting is on 4.0(Integrated Pipleline) you can do under extensions section of your website setting on your hosting control panel.
first:

[image]

and also make sure you remove WebDav module and handler in your web.config:

```
 <modules>
         <remove name="WebDAVModule" />
 </modules>
 <handlers>
         <remove name="WebDAV" />
 </handlers>
```

Answer (score 1):

I performed the same steps as above. But, I also needed to change the read write permissions on the app_code and custom directories. Hope that helps someone else out! :-)